# Webpack DefinePlugin from async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, webpack

I'd like to define some constants that are returned from an asynchronous resource. Is there anyway to do this in Webpack?

```
/* webpack.config.js */
module.exports = {
    ...,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            someVar: /* RETURN VARIABLE FROM ASYNC FUNCTION */
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way to do this is to [return a Promise](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-promise) from webpack configuration.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
...

module.exports = () => {
  return getYourAsyncResource().then((someVar) => {
    // Resolve as webpack configuration
    return {
      ...
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ someVar })
      ]
    };
  }) 
};
```

Comment: Would you be more specific please?  Maybe provide an example?

Comment: @MaxCoplan In the current version of webpack, likely a good way to do this is to return a `Promise` like this: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-promise . Let me amend the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: I'm sure your answer is correct.  Unfortunately, I use `vue-cli` with `vue.config.js`, which takes the same options as `webpack.config.js`, which made me think the answers would be the same.  Unfortunately this does not look like a possibility at this time https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3328 but may be supported soon https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/6275

Comment: @MaxCoplan There might be a way to work around that. If it's possible for you to run a script before webpack runs, you could set something to env after an async operation and then use `process.env` within webpack configuration to have access to it. It's simple to pull off with npm. :)